# export JSON file from angular app. URL is prefixed with 'unsafe' download says failed network error

Tags: angularjs, json, google-chrome, download, unsafe

I want to export a JSON file from an angular app. Here is the code I have:

app.js file:

```
app.config(['$compileProvider',
  function ($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|tel|file|blob):/);
}]);
```

my controller file:

```
this.$scope.exportJSON = "text/json;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(this.$scope.json));
```

index.html :

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="data: {{exportJSON}}" download="data.json">
  Export JSON
</a>
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. When I highlight the link the URL is prefixed with unsafe and then when I click it, it adds a download in the download bar of Chrome but says Failed-Network Error.

Any advice on this would be awesome

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it. I added these options into this in config:

```
$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|tel|file|blob|chrome-extension|data|local):/);
```